# knex, join and group

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have the following tables.

```
users {
  id,
  blog_id,
  deleted,
  ...other fields
}
```

and

```
blogs {
  id,
  posts: [],
  name,
  deleted,
}
```

It is possible within a single knex query to get one user with the blog posts?

I'm trying like this:

```
db
  .table('users')
  .where('id', id)
  .whereNot('deleted', true)
  .join('blogs', { 'blog_id': 'blogs.id' })
  .select();
```

But I receive the following error:

> error: column reference "deleted" is ambiguous

Is there a better way to do this? (only need posts from blog table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call another function ".columns([''])"-

```
db('users')
.leftJoin('blogs', 'blogs.id', 'users.blog_id')
.where('blogs.id', id)
.whereNot('blogs.deleted', true)
.columns(['users.id', 'blogs.name']); // what ever you want
```

Comment: basically i just want to fetch a user and from blogs to fetch the posts of the users, in the end to have something like user { ...user data, posts }

Comment: add another "column" on blog table as "user_id".

Comment: Its actually confusing what actually you are doing. I hope relationship between table is ok. Error should be gone after adding "columns()" call